# IE8 special char in Textarea and MVC2

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

I have a big problem with IE8

I have field TextArea, user write everything use lot of characters ç àèì áéí, show ok in textarea, debug in Javascript and Jquery ok too.
but when I send to MVC controller change characters special for "?"

I tryed in Chrome and FF IE 10 or 11 , its ok, problem is only IE 8

Comment: Have you added `<meta charset="utf-8">` inside the `head` tag of your page?

Comment: yes, but continue same problem.

Comment: Can you try [escaping](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) the string received from textarea and [unescaping](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) it at the MVC Controller?

Comment: I did lot of tests, turn off pc , but same problem.
in js i saw code %20 etc.

Comment: are you sending it via AJAX? or it is a normal Form Post? In case of Form Posting is it GET method or POST method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ajax

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "url",
     dataType: "json",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
     success: function (msg) {
         alert(msg);
     },
```

});

In the line "contetType" is possible change character type and send format what you want.